# How do I open the Gradle tasks window in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build, compilation

This is probably a very silly question, but I cannot find the gradle tasks window, like with compile, clean, build, instrument etc.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Gradle window was not in the Tool Windosws menu because the project was not linked with Gradle yet. IntelliJ eventually detected that the Gradle files in the project and suggested to link it.

After that (as mentioned by @RaGe) the Gradle window could be surfaced using:

View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle